# How to push associative data into array in php with only key => value pair

Tags: php, arrays

Hi i am trying to push data into array like this:

```
foreach($totalAnalyticsCountrywise['data']['countries'] as $countries){
array_push($mapData, $countries['country'] => $countries['clicks']);
}
```

but this is showing me red line error in netbeans how to push in?

The output must be this:

```
$mapData = array('IN' => 12, 'USA' => 31, 'RSA' => 24...);
```

Comment: Are `In, USA` and so on the keys of the values?

Comment: IN & USA are the values of key country & 12, 31 are the values of key clicks. i want to combine in the way i have show as to be the output so that i can esily show it on map

Comment: Array syntax is: `Array ( key => value , key => value , key => value ) ` and so on, not `:` <- With this I'm assuming it is part of the value and not the separator!

Comment: ok sorry... i have shown you the console output that looks like when you call the script & console the output through javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot push array element with keys; [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

I guess this is what you are trying to achieve.

```
foreach($totalAnalyticsCountrywise['data']['countries'] as $countryData){
    $mapData[$countryData['country']]  = $countryData['clicks'];
}
```

Comment: @Shaggie ^ If this is what you're looking for then your question is unclear. (Maybe you want to look into the manual for the correct array syntax: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: @Shaggie No as in your question you only have values without associative keys! And as in my last comment said, I think you want to look into the manual to get the correct array syntax